# Ol3 fail on the first pan (NaN, NaN)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, zoom, pan

I have a map on the link below:

http://gis.xyz/openlayers/openlayer.html
The map works well, however there is one thing what is frustrating me. When I load the page and the first thing what I try to do on the map is pan the map window change to white and the coordinates change to NaN, NaN. If I start with zoom in or out the map and the pan function work as well. Is there anybody who can provide me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your view center coordinates and zoom level are numbers. Currently they are strings (sometimes empty strings even), which leads to unexpected behavior. Something like

```
var zoomy = parseFloat(getParameterByName('zoomy') || 0);
var laty = parseFloat(getParameterByName('laty') || 0);
var lony = parseFloat(getParameterByName('lony') || 0);
```

Also make sure that your view center coordinates are in EPSG:3857 and x, y order. If it was your intention to use latitude and longitude (as your variable names suggest), then you'll have to change your view configuration:

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([lony, laty], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: zoomy
});
```

Comment: I changed them to numbers and it solved the problem. Thank you.